# How to get request URI without context path?

Tags: java, servlets

The Method [request.getRequestURI()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29) returns URI with context path.

For example, if the base URL of an application is `http://localhost:8080/myapp/` (i.e. the context path is **myapp**), and I call `request.getRequestURI()` for `http://localhost:8080/myapp/secure/users`, it will return `/myapp/secure/users`.

Is there any way we can get only this part `/secure/users`, i.e. the URI without context path?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between getRequestURI and getPathInfo methods in HttpServletRequest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931323/whats-the-difference-between-getrequesturi-and-getpathinfo-methods-in-httpservl)

Answer (score 178, accepted):

If you're inside a front contoller servlet which is mapped on a prefix pattern such as `/foo/*`, then you can just use [`HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29).

```
String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
// ...
```

Assuming that the servlet in your example is mapped on `/secure/*`, then this will return `/users` which would be the information of sole interest inside a typical front controller servlet.

If the servlet is however mapped on a suffix pattern such as `*.foo` (your URL examples however does not indicate that this is the case), or when you're actually inside a filter (when the to-be-invoked servlet is not necessarily determined yet, so `getPathInfo()` could return `null`), then your best bet is to substring the request URI yourself based on the context path's length using the usual `String` method:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
String path = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length());
// ...
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use this instead of `getServletPath()`? I'm writing a filter and I noticed that `getPathInfo()` returns `null`, but `getServletPath()` returns the path minus the context (suitable for passing on to the request dispatcher).

Comment: @JasonC: As answered, `getPathInfo()` returns null if front controller servlet is not mapped on a prefix pattern.

Comment: Yeah. I meant: is there a reason you prefer getPathInfo over getServletPath? A lot of the other high scored answers here don't use getServletPath either, which is what's making me suspicious of it and why I'm wondering. I've got a servlet project I'm working on and I'm trying to polish off my skills bit.

Comment: @JasonC: servlet path is subject to change when you have a servlet based MVC framework installed like JSF or Spring MVC. It will then represent the MVC framework's internal path (e.g. `/foo.xhtml` instead of `/foo.jsf`) and not the actual request URI (the one as enduser would see in browser's address bar). The original servlet path is in such case however resolveable as request attribute with key `RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_SERVLET_PATH`. In any way, the question explicitly asks for request URI (as in browser's address bar), so the answer is based on that.

Answer (score 90):

```
request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length())
```

Comment: +1 I think this is a better answer than getPathInfo due to the fact that getPathInfo can be null and other oddities. Various Spring code does getContextPath and removes it from the URI just as you have done instead of getPathInfo.

Answer (score 40):

With Spring you can do:

```
String path = new UrlPathHelper().getPathWithinApplication(request);
```

Comment: Of course it would make sense to keep an instance of the UrlPathHelper e.g. as a class member variable...

Comment: How can we get the actual request mapping url ? Please guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60446807/how-to-get-the-current-request-mapping-url-configured-at-controller-layer-when-r

Answer (score 16):

getPathInfo() sometimes return null. In documentation [HttpServletRequest](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29)

> This method returns null if there was no extra path information.

I need get path to file without context path in Filter and getPathInfo() return me null. So I use another method: httpRequest.getServletPath()

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    String newPath = parsePathToFile(httpRequest.getServletPath());
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you use request.getPathInfo() inside a Filter, you always seem to get null (at least with jetty).

This terse invalid bug + response alludes to the issue I think:

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=28323

I suspect it is related to the fact that filters run before the servlet gets the request.  It may be a container bug, or expected behaviour that I haven't been able to identify.

The contextPath is available though, so fforws solution works even in filters.  I don't like having to do it by hand, but the implementation is broken or

Answer (score 5):

A way to do this is to rest the servelet context path from request URI.

```
String p = request.getRequestURI();
String cp = getServletContext().getContextPath();

if (p.startsWith(cp)) {
  String.err.println(p.substring(cp.length());
}
```

Read [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath%28%29) .

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

```
String requestUriWithinApp = req.getPathInfo() == null
        ? req.getServletPath()
        : req.getServletPath() + req.getPathInfo();
```

`ServletPath` gets the part of the URL that calls the servlet. And
`PathInfo`returns any extra path information associated with the URL the client sent when it made this request. `PathInfo` may be null, depending on the URL used by the client.

For a more complete URI, you could also include the queryString. You could then use:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(req.getServletPath());
if (req.getPathInfo() != null) {
    sb.append(req.getPathInfo());
}
if (req.getQueryString() != null) {
    sb.append("?").append(req.getQueryString());
}
```

## Additional info

The formula of the requestURI is:

> requestURI = contextPath + servletPath + pathInfo

In your question you don't want to use the `contextPath`, so you need:

> servletPath + pathInfo

For example, if you have:

- a webapp context at `/catalog` and
- a `GardenServlet` for pattern `/garden/*` and
- a request send by the client for `/catalog/lawn/index.html`
- then the `pathInfo` is `/index.html`

This example is described in more detail in [Servlet Specification - 3.6 Request Path Elements](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-6.0.html#request-uri-path-processing).

The documentation of [Tuckey's UrlRewriteFilter](https://github.com/paultuckey/urlrewritefilter/blob/main/src/doc/manual/5.0/introduction.html) contains a more complete example of how the URL is composed in a ServletRequest.

```
    // http://hostname.com:80/mywebapp/servlet/MyServlet/a/b;c=123?d=789
    public static String getUrl(HttpServletRequest req) {
        String scheme = req.getScheme();             // http
        String serverName = req.getServerName();     // hostname.com
        int serverPort = req.getServerPort();        // 80
        String contextPath = req.getContextPath();   // /mywebapp
        String servletPath = req.getServletPath();   // /servlet/MyServlet
        String pathInfo = req.getPathInfo();         // /a/b;c=123
        String queryString = req.getQueryString();   // d=789

        // Reconstruct original requesting URL
        String url = scheme + "://" + serverName + ":" + serverPort + contextPath + servletPath;
        if (pathInfo != null) {
            url += pathInfo;
        }
        if (queryString != null) {
            url += "?" + queryString;
        }
        return url;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

May be you can just use the split method to eliminate the '/myapp'
for example:

```
string[] uris=request.getRequestURI().split("/");
string uri="/"+uri[1]+"/"+uris[2];
```

Comment: This will cause problem if I deploy my application as root and its base URL becomes http://localhost:8080/. In this case request.getRequestURI() would return "/secure/user" and your split method will cause problem here. The code should not be dependent upon deployment.