# What's the difference between getRequestURI and getPathInfo methods in HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm making a simple, very lightweight front-controller. I need to match request paths to different handlers (actions) in order to choose the correct one.

On my local machine [`HttpServletRequest.getPathInfo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo()) and [`HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI()) return the same results. But I'm not sure what will they return in the production environment.

So, what's the difference between these method and what should I choose?

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/3542297#3542297) useful as well.

Comment: @BalusC: thanks, I've been already using some tips from that answer.

Comment: This explains the difference with a nice diagram: https://agiletribe.wordpress.com/2016/02/23/httpservletrequest-path-decoding/

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`getPathInfo()` gives the extra path information after the URI, used to access your Servlet, where as `getRequestURI()` gives the complete URI.

I would have thought they would be different, given a Servlet must be configured with its own URI pattern in the first place; I don't think I've ever served a Servlet from root (/).

For example if Servlet 'Foo' is mapped to URI '/foo' then I would have thought the URI:

```
/foo/path/to/resource
```

Would result in:

```
RequestURI = /foo/path/to/resource
```

and

```
PathInfo = /path/to/resource
```

Comment: worth mentioning about decoding behavior.

getRequestURI() does not decode the string. Where getPathInfo() does decode.

Comment: In some cases `getRequestURI()` gives me the string `"/foo/path/to/resource"` as expected, but `getPathInfo()` for the same `HttpServletRequest` object gives me `null`. What in the world is going on? **EDIT: It is answered below by the user "30thh".**

Answer (score 554):

I will put a small comparison table here (just to have it somewhere):

Servlet is mapped as `/test%3F/*` and the application is deployed under `/app`.

`http://30thh.loc:8480/app/test%3F/a%3F+b;jsessionid=S%3F+ID?p+1=c+d&p+2=e+f#a`

```
Method              URL-Decoded Result           
----------------------------------------------------
getContextPath()        no      /app
getLocalAddr()                  127.0.0.1
getLocalName()                  30thh.loc
getLocalPort()                  8480
getMethod()                     GET
getPathInfo()           yes     /a?+b
getProtocol()                   HTTP/1.1
getQueryString()        no      p+1=c+d&p+2=e+f
getRequestedSessionId() no      S%3F+ID
getRequestURI()         no      /app/test%3F/a%3F+b;jsessionid=S+ID
getRequestURL()         no      http://30thh.loc:8480/app/test%3F/a%3F+b;jsessionid=S+ID
getScheme()                     http
getServerName()                 30thh.loc
getServerPort()                 8480
getServletPath()        yes     /test?
getParameterNames()     yes     [p 2, p 1]
getParameter("p 1")     yes     c d
```

---

In the example above the server is running on the `localhost:8480` and the name `30thh.loc` was put into OS `hosts` file.

**Comments**

- "+" is handled as space only in the query string
- Anchor "#a" is not transferred to the server. Only the browser can work with it.
- If the `url-pattern` in the servlet mapping does not end with `*` (for example `/test` or `*.jsp`), `getPathInfo()` returns `null`.

**If Spring MVC is used**

- Method `getPathInfo()` returns `null`.
- Method `getServletPath()` returns the part between the context path and the session ID. In the example above the value would be `/test?/a?+b`
- Be careful with URL encoded parts of `@RequestMapping` and `@RequestParam` in Spring. It is buggy (current version 3.2.4) and is usually [not working as expected](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-11101).

Comment: I'm printing your answer and put it up as a poster on our office. That's how useful it is!

Comment: `If the url-pattern in the servlet mapping does not end with * (for example /test or *.jsp), getPathInfo() returns null.` brilliant.

Comment: I believe both `getRequestURI()` and `getRequestURL()` should return non-decoded jsessionid, in this case `S%3F+ID`. At least it does on Tomcat/8.5.6.

Answer (score 42):

Let's break down the full URL that a client would type into their address bar to reach your servlet:

http://www.example.com:80/awesome-application/path/to/servlet/path/info?a=1&b=2#boo

The parts are:

1. scheme: `http`
2. hostname: `www.example.com`
3. port: `80`
4. context path: `awesome-application`
5. servlet path: `path/to/servlet`
6. path info: `path/info`
7. query: `a=1&b=2`
8. fragment: `boo`

The request URI (returned by [getRequestURI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI())) corresponds to parts 4, 5 and 6.

(incidentally, even though you're not asking for this, the method [getRequestURL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL()) would give you parts 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6).

Now:

- part 4 (the context path) is used to select your particular application out of many other applications that may be running in the server
- part 5 (the servlet path) is used to select a particular servlet out of many other servlets that may be bundled in your application's WAR
- part 6 (the path info) is interpreted by your servlet's logic (e.g. it may point to some resource controlled by your servlet).
- part 7 (the query) is also made available to your servlet using [getQueryString](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString--)
- part 8 (the fragment) is not even sent to the server and is relevant and known only to the client

The following always holds (except for URL encoding differences):

```
requestURI = contextPath + servletPath + pathInfo
```

The following example from the [Servlet 3.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1489097281_810668568503a957ccb828d490dff1df) is very helpful:

---

**Note:** image follows, I don't have the time to recreate in HTML:

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Consider the following servlet conf:

```xml
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>NewServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>NewServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>NewServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/NewServlet/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Now, when I hit the URL `http://localhost:8084/JSPTemp1/NewServlet/jhi`, it will invoke `NewServlet` as it is mapped with the pattern described above.

Here:

```
getRequestURI() =  /JSPTemp1/NewServlet/jhi
getPathInfo() = /jhi
```

We have those ones:

- `getPathInfo()`

  > **returns**
  >   a String, decoded by the web container, specifying extra path information that comes after the servlet path but before the query string in the request URL; or null if the URL does not have any extra path information
- `getRequestURI()`

  > **returns**
  >   a String containing the part of the URL from the protocol name up to the query string