# Image not getting Displayed from database

Tags: java, mysql, image, jsp, jstl

I have stored the image in a folder and saved the path in mySql database. When i try to display the image in jsp page, image is not getting displayed. But when i try to print the path i can see the path getting displayed. Not sure where i am going wrong, can someone help me..

Servlet:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
List sname = new ArrayList();
List photo1 = new ArrayList();
DAO dao = new DAO();
for(Newsfeed nfc: dao.display()) // dao.display() - Hibernate DAO
 {
      sname.add(nfc.getUsername());
      photo1.add(nfc.getPhoto());
 }
 session.setAttribute("photo1", photo1);
 session.setAttribute("sname", sname);
 RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/upload.jsp");
 rd.forward(request, response);
```

JSP Page:

```
  <% List sname = (List) session.getAttribute("sname");
  List photo1 = (List) session.getAttribute("photo1"); %>
  <c:forEach items="${photo1}" var="pic">
  <img src="<c:url value="${pic}"/>"/>  <br>
  </c:forEach>
```

But instead if i try to display the path name, its working

```
 <c:forEach items="${photo1}" var="pic">
  ${pic} <br>
  </c:forEach>
```

if i run this, i get the output

E:/upload/thres.gif
E:/upload/audio.png

Not sure how to display this as an image...

Comment: To display in jsp you'd need valid links - not just file paths. If you need to store in filesytem, try saving into your webapps folder and then transform file path to web- path. Better yet would be to put images into db as blob

Comment: are you using spring mvc or normal servlet?

Comment: @Jan i will try to save in web-path folder and check...

Comment: @AnantLaxmikantBobde normal servlet..

Comment: Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23458549/how-to-display-image-from-local-path-from-jsp

Answer (score 0):

The path is the local file path. Visitors will not be able to fetch that from the website. You will need to put it to a publicly accessible folder of a web server and use that link.

Comment: is it possible to check with localhost...?