# Framing multiple servlet request url pattern

Tags: java, servlets

I am using servlet to get request from frontend.
Am i able to make single servlet which could do multiple operation based on url pattern?
Here will be my url mapping

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/HelloServletOne</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/HelloServletTwo</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

That means if i hit to the url as framed below it should invoke its own functionalities.

- URL:/HelloServlet: it should do function 1
- URL:/HelloServletOne: it should do function 2
- URL:/HelloServletTwo: it should do function 3 etc.

How can i achive this by extending servlet.?
Code/link examples are much appreciated.

Comment: It seems likely that you could do that, but a different approach might be to use one servlet mapping but use the HTTP verbs to differentiate between the actions that you take in a way that is similar to REST. goGet method retrieves, doPut method updates, doPost inserts, doDelete deletes. I think I'd go in that direction rather than the servlet mapping approach you suggest.

Comment: Just to understand you right - you want to use one servlet (HelloWorld). Based on the URL a different method inside your HelloWorld servlet should be invoked?

Comment: @DaveHowes It can be achievable using rest service. but i am not good at that.If i am able to achieve this using servlet my work will get easier.:)

Comment: Yes @swinkler. Using single servlet helloworld the requested url pattern should be categorized.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regarding your url-pattern you need to know what URL was called. Because a request can be made due to different http-methods (GET, POST etc.) you can use parts of the [FrontController Pattern](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/frontcontroller-135648.html)

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

  private static final String SERLVET = "HelloServlet";
  private static final String SERLVET_ONE = "HelloServletOne";
  private static final String SERLVET_TWO = "HelloServletTwo";

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(req, resp);
  }

  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(req, resp);
  }

  private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    String path = req.getServletPath();
    switch (path) {
      case SERLVET:
        // ... call your function1
        break;
      case SERLVET_ONE:
        // ... call your function2
        break;

      case SERLVET_TWO:
        // ... call your function3
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    // do something else
  }

}
```

The getServletPath method may only work for explicit url-patterns like you have given. For other information on the URL check [this link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/610432/java-Web-Component-SCWCD/certification/getContextPath-getServletPath-getPathInfo)

Comment: Thanks @swinkler Yes this is the answer what i am expecting . This link is helped me too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931323/whats-the-difference-between-getrequesturi-and-getpathinfo-methods-in-httpservl

Answer (score 0):

You should not use three different Servlet for this purpose. You should use different methods of Servlet to achieve this.

Use **doGet** method for get data.
Use **doPost** method for insert data.
Use **doPut** method for update data.
Use **doDelete** method for delete data.

Please refer [servlet api documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)) for more details.

**EDIT:**
Read more about this [here](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr154/servlet-2_5-changelog.html#pgfId-1042938).
It says the url mapping you have provided must work if you are working with servlet api version **2.5 or greater**.
Also, please make sure that you have provided **fully qualified name of servlet class** in `<servlet-name>`.

Comment: This is not the answer i am looking for. i need to call some function based on url pattern. Please check the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle multiple requests by the same servlet by making a contract to have a request parameter like `'ACTION'`. Then in your forms add this as hidden field with values like `'ACTION_1'` and `'ACTION_2'` and `'ACTION_3'`. So, in `doPost()` you can check this parameter value and can invoke respective handling methods in same servlet.

```
class YourServlet extends HttpServlet{

      public void doPost(HttpReq req, HttpResp resp){
               String action = reg.getParameter('ACTION');
               if('ACTION_1'.equals(action)){
                   doAction_1();
               }
               if('ACTION_2'.equals(action)){
                   doAction_2()
               } 
               if('ACTION_3'.equals(action)){
                   doAction_3()
               }
               else {
                   defaultAction();
               }
      }

}
```

Comment: This can be achieved in single url pattern. But for me client side api's are already exposed and am not able to do any changes. Using those url pattern i need to differentiate the request come from client side.

Comment: Are you able to work with `spring-mvc` framework? If yes, you can do what you want easily using `MultiActionController`. @MadhukarHebbar

Comment: Yes it can be achievable using many ways, but as per the question i am asking is it able to implement using servlets. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I made into.

`HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI()` returns the URL pattern including /* with query parameter if exist, and `HttpServletRequest.getPathInfo()` returns the part matched by /* (or null for exact match).

Here in my case i need `getPathInfo()` where it will returns 
HelloServlet,HelloServletOne or HelloServletTwo based on request.
Thanks.