# How to found out url with which the request arrived at error handler?

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, request, custom-error-handling

I send following http request:

```
http://localhost:8081/member/createCompany/getSmallThumbnail/
```

On server side I hit into controller method:

```
@RequestMapping("/error")
public String error(Model model, HttpServletRequest request){
    if(request.getRequestURI().contains("thumbnail")){
        System.out.println("thumbnail accepted");
     }
     request.toString();
     model.addAttribute("message", "page not found");
     return "errorPage";
}
```

At this method I want to know url with which the request arrived.

If in debug I stop inside this method I see information needed for me:
[image]

But I cannot find method in request which will return this.

Please help to return url which I want.

### P.S.

Actually I have not mapped controller in my spring mvc application(url is broken) for `http://localhost:8081/member/createCompany/getSmallThumbnail/`. This url("/error") configured in web.xml as error page.

Comment: Your handler is mapped to `/error`, so the path would be `/error` (plus any path specified at your `@Controller`).

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I understand it - but I need to get previous url.

Comment: What is _previous url_? I don't understand your question. The client sends a request, Spring determines the handler based on the path. If you're inside that handler, you know what that path is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between getRequestURI and getPathInfo methods in HttpServletRequest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931323/whats-the-difference-between-getrequesturi-and-getpathinfo-methods-in-httpservl)

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I described my flow. I need to get **/member/createCompany/getSmallThumbnail/**  please explain how can I achieve it ?

Comment: I didn't found answers in linked question

Comment: If your path is `/member/createCompany/getSmallThumbnail/`, then Spring would have invoked a handler method that's mapped to `/member/createCompany/getSmallThumbnail/`. That is static information. You already know that it's `/member/createCompany/getSmallThumbnail/`. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis actually I have not controller method for http://localhost:8081/member/createCompany/getSmallThumbnail/  this url is broken thus I hit into this handler. It is configured in web.xml

Comment: Ok, that's a completely different question then. Please add that information into your question. It's an `<error-page>` mapping.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis topic update, thanks for correction

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your request got redispatched to `/error` (presumably for error processing).

If this framework follows the normal Servlet error dispatching behavior, then your original request can be found in the `HttpServletRequest.getAttributes()` under the various [`javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher.ERROR_*`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) keys.

- `ERROR_EXCEPTION` - The exception object
- `ERROR_EXCEPTION_TYPE` - The type of exception object
- `ERROR_MESSAGE` - the exception message
- `ERROR_REQUEST_URI` - the original request uri that caused the error dispatch
- `ERROR_SERVLET_NAME` - the name of the servlet that caused the error
- `ERROR_STATUS_CODE` - the response status code determined for this error dispatch

What you want is

```java
String originalUri = (String) request.getAttribute(
                                       RequestDispatcher.ERROR_REQUEST_URI)
```