# Converting uncaught exception to Json in embedded jetty

Tags: json, exception, embedded-jetty

I am using Embedded Jetty in my Java project. I am throwing `RuntimeException` at few places but they are resulting in `500` error code and raw html is returned in response.

My application is rest API application, so I want to return Exception message to client in `JSON` format.

I tried `ErrorHandler` class but I am not getting how to get thrown Exception in this class. Please help me with this.

```
ServletContextHandler jettyHandler =
        new ServletContextHandler(jettyServer, "/");
jettyHandler.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler());
```

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/32910916/775715

Comment: I am not using any annotations.

Comment: The behavior outlined in the linked answer still applies.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar did you find a solution for this issue?