# URL patterns in web.xml too permissive?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web.xml

I have a servlet with `web.xml` as follows:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
  id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mydomain.myapp.MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/rest1*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/rest2*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/rest3*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Ultimately, the servlet should support REST calls like `GET` from `http://myserver/myapp/rest1?param=1`.

However, what happens is that all invocations of URLs that start with `http://myserver/myapp/` from a browser apparently lead to calls to the servlet's `doGet()` method with `request.pathInfo() == null`.

But then, with the given `url-pattern`s, should the URL `http://myserver/myapp/rest1?param=1` not lead to `"/rest1".equals(request.pathInfo())` and should a URL pattern such as `http://myserver/myapp/foo` not lead to HTTP response 404 from the servlet?

The servlet is running on Apache Tomcat 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing to these URL patterns proved most effective:

```
<url-pattern></url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/rest1</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/rest2</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/rest3</url-pattern>
```

The key was changing from `/` to the empty URL pattern. The difference between the two and other key patterns is nicely explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4140659/1789384) previous answer.

I am now using `getServletPath()` instead of `getPathInfo()` for further dispatching inside `doGet()`. The difference between those and other functions (and why `getPathInfo()` now always returns `null`) is nicely explained in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21046620/1789384) previous answer.

Comment: Note that this is also explained in the servlet specification. I know more people don't usually read specs because they are dry and unreadable, but the Java Servlet Specification isn't one of those documents: it's quite readable and answers most questions about how things should behave.

Comment: @ChristopherSchulz Thx for participating in answering as a senior Tomcat expert. BTW, I have just deleted that other recent question about confusion between response codes 401/501. I was being stupid about `curl`'s command line options. Tried with `curl -I` where `curl -i` would have been appropriate. Re-thx.

Comment: Yes, using `curl -I` will issue a `HEAD` request. If your servlet doesn't support `doHead`, then you'll get a 501 response. `-i` looks like what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

change the `<url-pattern>/rest1*</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/rest1/*</url-pattern>`