# How can i call a parametrized method of java class into a servlet doget method

Tags: java, sql, servlets, jdbc, methods

I have a java class  where i have a method which is returning me a json i want to call that method into my servlet doGet method so that i can make a AJAX call later

but while calling the java class method (**Outlet.Outlet**) it asks for a parameter to pass i dont know what to pass there 
please have a look into my code

this is my java class

```
public class Outlet {
static Connection con = null;
static Statement statement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;

public static String Outlet(String idDB) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    con = DBConnection.createConnection();
    statement = con.createStatement();

    String sql="select CUSTOMERDESCRIPTOR as OUTLETNAME from ecustomer where CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER in(select CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER from mt_distributrol where mt_distributr_vcdistributrcode = '"+idDB+"')";

  System.out.println("iddb  :"+idDB);
    try {

        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            list.add(resultSet.getString("OUTLETNAME"));

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
    System.out.println("Json Outlet :"+json);
    return json;
}
```

}

In the above java class i am returning a Json and i want to call that method into my servlet doGost

my doGet is

```
    try {
        String json = Outlet.Outlet();  //what should i pass here as a parameter
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(json);
        System.out.println("dheeraj"+json);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

if i am passing idDB then it throws error.please anybody having any knowledge help me out

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: By the way, you might want to research "SQL Injection" before writing more SQL queries like that

Comment: check you DB for a valid `mt_distributr_vcdistributrcode`

Comment: @cricket_007 in servlet  when i am calling Outlet.Outlet() it says to pass a parameter what parameter should i pass? and what is SQL INJECTION ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat what ?? i didn't get you

Comment: Like I said, please research SQL Injection elsewhere.

Comment: `where mt_distributr_vcdistributrcode = '"+idDB+"'`  - so check the DB for a valid value

Comment: @ScaryWombat this value is comming from user login query based on that only

Comment: @ScaryWombat  we can disscuss here.

Comment: where do you think you will get the value from? HTML? Does it display somewhere?

Comment: you are talking about idDB? no i am not getting this value from HTML..i am getting this value from a query which is login query for login user..this value is based on the user loging in so i want to use this value "idDB" in other class to display somthing on the basis of user who is looged in

Answer (score 1):

**Please read [OWASP - SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) and learn about PreparedStatements**

First, methods should not start with capital letter, so rather you could name it like `Outlet.findById` rather than `Outlet.Outlet` (the method should not be  the same as the class; it is really confusing to read), and you can get parameters from the request

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    String s = Outlet.findById(id);
```

When calling the API, you add `?id=value`

Or you can get the final part of the path from `request`, assuming your API is setup like `/path/ids/value` - Refer [What's the difference between getRequestURI and getPathInfo methods in HttpServletRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931323/whats-the-difference-between-getrequesturi-and-getpathinfo-methods-in-httpservl) for options with this

Before doing this, of course you should double-check that query you are running actually returns data when querying the database directly.

Comment: hey from where you are getting this "id" ?

Comment: on my ui i don't have any input feild for idDB.. its is comming from loging query like there is a form form loging in on mu ui when ever a user looged in i run a query which checks username and pasword and also i get that value **idDB** from that query now i am passing that value into the java class methot which is **Outlet** and in that method i am using idDB in a query

Comment: i didn't get you :(

Comment: okay... I don't know your API, or your app's logic... The answer is still the same. You need to form that URL so that you can actually get an ID. Either that is part of the path, `http/your.api.com/someAPI/ids/x` to get that ID, or you can put `?id=x` at the end

Comment: Then name `idDB` is not important here. The parameter can be named anything in your code. It does not mean that your API needs to use the same thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183921/discussion-between-dheeraj-kumar-and-cricket-007).

Comment: No... If you want to only learn Javascript terms, I don't really think you should be writing Java sevlets... Node.JS can run web servers and can run AJAX calls, and do SQL things, and JSON, etc...