# Extends OncePerRequestFilter bypass specific URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, filter, spring-security

I use Spring Boot 2.5.6. I want to skip specific URL (`/doc.html`).

I have created a `JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter` extending `OncePerRequestFilter`

```java
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //the logic of authentication
}
```

And then I create `SecurityConfig` extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web)
            throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                .antMatchers("/doc.html");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
           .csrf().disable()
           .sessionManagement()
               .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
           .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/doc.html").anonymous()
               .and()
           .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/doc.html");
```

but when I access `localhost:8080/doc.html`, the **`/doc.html`** didn't skip;

and I also try to override `shouldNotFilter` in `JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.java`, but it did't work also:

```java
@Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
        return (
                new AntPathMatcher().match("/doc.html", request.getServletPath()));
    }
```

Comment: why have you created a filter that already exists in spring security? please google the spring security reference and read the chapter on jwt

Comment: Your filter is an component, registered as part of the regular filter chain. It isn't part of the special security filter chain and thus will execute on each request.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple array inside `JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter` if you want to bypass for multiple Urls.

For example:

```
    private static final String[] excluded_urls = {
            "/login",
            "**/doc.html"
    };
```

And then override `shouldNotFilter` method:

```
    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
        String url = request.getRequestURI();
        return Stream.of(excluded_urls).anyMatch(x -> pathMatcher.match(x, url));
    }
```

Where

```
pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();
//can be injected or create wherever required
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter` will be picked up by Spring as a component and will be included in the filter chain and will **not** be automatically excluded through your `SecurityConfig`.

So overwriting `shouldNotFilter` seems like a valid approach and should work as expected.

You could try to use `request.getRequestURI()` instead of `request.getServletPath()` in order to ensure to match the actual request path. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931323/whats-the-difference-between-getrequesturi-and-getpathinfo-methods-in-httpservl) for further details.