# request.getServletPath() returned null from Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I made a filter to capture `HttpServletRequest` sevlet path from all requests

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)res;

    // debug to see the output
    String path = request.getServletPath();

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

There is a URL in jsp that has no controller or view mapped to it

```
<div>
    <spring:url value="/app" var="app_url" htmlEscape="true"/>
    <a href="${app_url}"><spring:message code="label_3rd_app" /></a>
</div>
```

However, when click on the url while debugging on the filter, I see `request.getServletPath()` value from two request:

```
/null
/null/app
```

My question is why `request.getServletPath()` never returns `/app` instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're getting null because

```
request.getServletPath();
```

is for Servlets, and you're doing it inside a Filter. To get it in a Filter you have to manually build it like this:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
String path = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length());
```

**more info why:**

[How to get request URI without context path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278083/how-to-get-request-uri-without-context-path)

Comment: This is not an equivalent solution. getServletPath() returns the uri-decoded path "/servlet path/foo", while getRequestURI() returns an uri-encoded path "/context/servlet%20path/foo".

Answer (score 1):

Mr. Lalibertes solution is not working correctly as the result of `getRequestURI` is uri-encoded and `getServletPath` is not.

Better use Springs UrlPathHelper for getting the servlet path in such situations.

```
new org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper().getPathWithinApplication(servletRequest);
```

This method delivers the uri-decoded servlet path as `getServletPath` would have - if it would'nt be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

For people coming to this question just because your context path was null (like me): I was calling `request.getContextPath()` in a background thread.

The request then became 'out of scope', if I understand this bug report discussion correctly: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=401768

Also, I know I'm not supposed to use normal threads in servlet environments, but use `Executor` instead. But the problem would probably remain: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/232135.

Solution was to extract all needed info from the request before handing off to background thread.